# Pandoc not rendering bold columns when knitting html

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

In my R markdown file, I have the following data:

````
```{r}
library(pander)

d <- data.frame(replicate(10,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)))
d <- head(d)

pandoc.table(d, emphasize.strong.cols = 1)

```
````

My goal is to use `pandoc` to highlight the values in the first column as bold, but the table in the resulting html file after using `Knit HTML` is not what is expected:

[image]

Is there a reason why this might be happening?  Here is the [documentation](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#brew-to-pandoc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works , but one can only specify one column

```
pander(d, emphasize.strong.cols = 1)
```

Comment: That's because `pander` returns a special object that `knitr` knows how to render, while `pandoc.table` writes to the `stdout` by default -- one of the things why you should probably never use `pandoc.table`, but instead the general S3 `pander` method. What do you mean by "one can only specify one column"?